# R: How to interpret square brackets with forms like y[i : j - k]

Tags: r

Can you help me understand how R interprets square brackets with forms such as `y[i:j - k]`?

dummy data:

```
y <- c(1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8)
```

Here's what I *do* understand:

- `y[i]` is the *i*th element of vector y.
- `y[i:j]` is the *i*th to *j*th element (inclusive) of vector y.
- `y[-i]` is vector y without the first *i* elements. etc. etc.

However, what I don't understand is what happens when you start mixing these options, and I haven't found a good resource for explaining it.

For example:

```
y[1-1:4]
[1] 5 7 8
```

So `y[1-1:4]` returns the vector without the first three elements. But why?

and

```
y[1-4]
[1] 1 2 5 7 8
```

So `y[1-4]` returns the vector without the third element. Is that because 1-4 = -3 and it's interpretting it the same as `y[-3]`? If so, that doesn't seem consistent with my previous example where `y[1-1:4]` would presumably be interpretted as `y[0:4]`, but that isn't the case.

and

```
y[1:1+2-1]
[1] 2
```

Why does this return the second element? I encountered this while I was trying to code something along the lines of:  `y[i:i + j - k]` and it took me a while to figure out that I should write `y[i:(i + j - k)]` so the parenthesis captured the whole of the right-hand-side of the colon. But I still can't figure out what logic R was doing when I didn't have those brackets.

Thanks!

Comment: Try `?Syntax`. It's a matter of precedence.

Comment: Thanks @SmokeyShakers, that's really useful. I can see that in the example of `y[1:1+2-1]` it's performing the sequence `[1:1]` first since the sequence operator has precedenceand then `[+2-1]` to that, so it's just fetching the first element and adding 1 to it. However, what's going on with `[1-1:4]`? How does that one work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's best to look closer at precedence and the integer sequences you use for subsetting. These are evaluated *before* subsetting with `[]`. Note that `-` is a function with two arguments (`1`, `1:4`) which are evaluated beforehand and so

```
> 1-1:4
[1]  0 -1 -2 -3
```

Negative indices in `[]` mean exclusion of the corresponding elements. There is no "0" element (and so subsetting at `0` returns an empty vector of the present type -- `numeric(0)`). We thus expect `y[1-1:4]` to drop the first three elements in `y` and return the remainder.

As you write correctly `y[1-4]` is `y[-3]`, i.e. omission of the third element.

Similar as above, in `1:1+2-1`, `1:1` evaluates to a one-element vector `1`, the rest is simple arithmetic.

For more on operator precedence, see [Hadley's excellent book](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/expressions.html#grammar).

Comment: Thank you, this makes complete sense. I didn't even check to see what the result of `1-1:4` was in the console before asking my question - I'll check that before I post next time, but your response is exactly what I needed. Thank you again :)